# Deployment Issues with Flask & Gunicorn [No Module Found Exception]

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn

I have developed a flask application and now I am trying to deploy it on a Linux server. I've followed explanation from [Linode documentation](https://www.linode.com/docs/guides/flask-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu/#more-information) from A to Z, but I end up stack when setting `supervisor`.

Basically, whenever I enter my virtual environment where ALL packages are installed (Python 3.7), I can turn on the server by running:

```
source venv/bin/activate
gunicorn -w 3 flask_app:app
```

But, when I setup supervior which I've installed within virtual environment, with pip (as explained in documentation), I am getting following error

```
[2022-06-06 02:44:54 +0000] [9205] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2022-06-06 02:44:54 +0000] [9209] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 9209
[2022-06-06 02:44:54 +0000] [9209] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 129, in init_process
    self.load_wsgi()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 138, in load_wsgi
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 41, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 375, in import_app
    __import__(module)
  File "/var/www/app/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from app.db import db_session
  File "/var/www/app/db.py", line 1, in <module>
    from flask import current_app, g
ImportError: No module named flask
```

Any ideas? First thing that pops out to me is that environment is in Python 3.7, but supervisor seems to be looking into Python 2.7, how do I address this?

Comment: Looks like your virtualenv is python2.7 based, not python3.7.  You probably need to update/change your virtualenv to be python3.7.

Comment: When I try to user Python interpreter I get 3.7 though